# What is the Space Complexity of Bit Sorting?

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, space, space-complexity

What is the Space Complexity of Bit Sorting? According to its Best and Average case it's O(n). I'm wondering what is its space complexity

Source title: Bit Sorting: New technique for Sorting

The IEEE Research is only focus on Time Complexity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its `O(n)` since you don't create any new elements in function of some variable. Just checking it bits representations and swapping positions. So basically, during those steps:

```
Step 1: convert all elements into binary form but converted elements are in same BIT
sequence form.
Step 2: find elements whose first leftmost bit is 1
Step 3: repeat step 2 to all selected elements until get single BIT sequence number
Step 4: swap selected BIT sequence with last element of an array
Step 5: repeat step2, step3 and step4 until all elements are sorted
Step 6: convert sorted BIT sequence elements into decimal number
```

in theory, you don't have any new elements when you have direct access to bit values of given elements.

However, if you do implement in terms of creating deep copies of given elements in its bit representations, and then again, convert back to elements, its still `O(n)` (just `3*n`). Now swapping with deep copy of elements, you still need up to `n` new memory spaces (`n` is when you always take new space in memory when swapping). Best case scenario when swapping with deep copy is you need just one memory space. Same goes for pointer swapping. So overall, its `O(n)`.